# Is the Stefan's law valid for any surface geometry?

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation

Suppose I have an ellipsoid instead of a sphere. I'd like to know whether I can still use Stefan's law to determine the intrinsic temperature of the object making use of surface area of the ellipsoid? Or does this violate the law?

Comment: Are you talking about a situation where you *know* the total power output from the ellipsoid, or where you are observing flux from the ellipsoid at a distance?

Answer (score 1):

The shape of object does not change anything. The Stefan (or Stefan-Boltzmann in some countries) law states that radiative power output PER UNIT AREA is proportional to the 4th power of temperature.

Of course, to get total power output you have to multiply the number jou get from Stefan law with the area of your example elipsoid.